# Implement RRule using javascript rrule.min.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, python-dateutil, rrule, recurring-events

I am trying to include the library https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule to my webpage.

But I recieve the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

I have tried with

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/dist/es5/rrule-tz.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

import { RRule, RRuleSet, rrulestr } from 'rrule'
alert(rrulestr('DTSTART:20120201T023000Z\nRRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;COUNT=5')
)

});
</script>
</head>
<body>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think `import {}` syntax is not supported natively in browsers. Put it in a file and use a transpiler like babel to get js file, and use that. Or use normal JS syntax.

Comment: I tried with import * from 'rrule' but I am not successful.

Comment: @psinaught `import` is supported if the file was loaded as a module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/dist/es5/rrule-tz.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

alert(rrule.rrulestr('DTSTART:20120201T023000Z\nRRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;COUNT=5'));

});
</script>
</head>
<body>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Code Guy As far as I understand - `{` in `import {`

Comment: It would be helpful if you eloborated on your solution for future readers. What was the error, how does your answer solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Import does not work inside script tag, use below solution where a rrule minified js is inserted and functions used.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/dist/es5/rrule-tz.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            const RRule = rrule.RRule;

            const rule = new RRule({
                freq: RRule.WEEKLY,
                interval: 5,
                byweekday: [RRule.MO, RRule.FR],
                dtstart: new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 1, 1, 10, 30)),
                until: new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 12, 31))
            });

            alert(rule.between(new Date(Date.UTC(2018, 7, 1)), new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 8, 1))));
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```